# Tensorflow: extract varying size patches at same center

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

## Context

As part of my university project I'm trying to implement the semantic image segmentation approach used in this paper: http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/ning-05.pdf

I now have a dataset that consist of *images* (.jpg) and *segmentation_masks* (.png). The authors of the paper split their original images into overlapping windows (e.g. 40 x 40 pixels), where the centre of each is 4 pixels apart.

## What I'm trying to do

My plan is to use `tf.image.extract_patches()` to create larger patches of the *images* (e.g. 40x40) and smaller patches of *segmentation_masks* (e.g. 4x4) where the centres of the *patch pairs* match.
I then plan to reduce the *segmentation_mask* patch to a single value (i.e. label).

## Where it's going wrong

I mapped the following function to my dataset:

```
def load_patches_labels(datapoint):

    img_patches = tf.image.extract_patches(
        images = datapoint['image'],
        sizes = [1, patch_size_big, patch_size_big, 1],
        strides = [1, stride, stride, 1],
        rates = [1, 1, 1, 1],
        padding = 'VALID'
    )
    
    sm_patches = tf.image.extract_patches(
        images = datapoint['segmentation_mask'],
        sizes = [1, patch_size_small, patch_size_small, 1],
        strides = [1, stride, stride, 1],
        rates = [1, 1, 1, 1],
        padding = 'VALID'
    )

    img_patches_flat = tf.reshape(img_patches, shape=(-1, patch_size_big, patch_size_big, 3))
    sm_patches_flat = tf.reshape(sm_patches, shape=(-1, patch_size_small, patch_size_small, 3))

    img_patches_flat, sm_patches_flat = normalize(img_patches_flat, sm_patches_flat)

    return img_patches_flat, sm_patches_flat
```

When `patch_size_big == patch_size_small` then the *image* and the *seg_mask* patches appear to correspond to each other. However as soon as I lower `patch_size_small` (e.g. big: 128 and small: 64) the patches no longer seem to correspond (see attached [drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2ZUD.png)).

- How would I achieve different size patches with corresponding centres?

  - Am I perhaps misunderstanding how [extract_patches](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/extract_patches) works? (are the patches anchored at index 0,0 as opposed to their center, or does the `sizes` argument influence strides in some way?)
- As a side question: Is there a more straightforward way to go from the image/seg_mask pairs to patch/center_pixel_label pairs? (see "What I'm trying to do")

Comment: It just occurred to me that I can probably achieve this by leaving the patch sizes the same and then use [tf.image.central_crop()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/central_crop) to achieve my goal.